# .Net Core Rest API listen for requests by domain or server name instead of IP address or a local network

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am developing a .Net Core REST API for an Android app which is written in Dart/Flutter, both .Net Core and android app are connected to the same local network, right now I am sending requests to server by using it's IP address, however I want to make it easy for end users to use the app since they have limited knowledge of configuring stuff.

How can I link a local domain to the server or at least use server name instead of ip address for sending requests, in that case it would have saved me a lot of time and hassle with end users.
Do I need a DNS server for this and is it easy to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you should set up a DNS server in your local network. If you want to access the app by using domain, you should make sure the android app is also inside that local network.

A DNS server is a computer server that contains a database of public IP addresses and their associated hostnames, and in most cases serves to resolve, or translate, those names to IP addresses as requested.

More details about how to set up a DNS server and configure a DNS server , you could refer to below article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/814591/how-to-install-and-configure-dns-server-in-windows-server-2003

Comment: The .Net Core app is also deployed to end user machine running on Windows 10, so it would be a complicated task to ship a DNS server and spin it up automatically during the setup, what I need is a straight-forward solution.

Comment: In my opinion, without using DNS server the Android app couldn't know the domain mapped IP address.